# Android - Create Button Programmatically

Tags: android, button

I have an Activity called GameLoop (class which extends Activity).
But instead of using an xml file for the layout, i'm using a class for it, since I want to be able to draw to a canvas. (I've seen on some tutorials this is what you're supposed to do)

The layout class is called GameLoopLayout.

I have a game loop running in the layout class, I can render bitmaps to the screen and control the FPS, everything is fine.
But now I want to add a button to it, but since i'm not using an xml layout file, I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me out please?

What I'm doing atm:

GameLoopLayout:

```
Button button;
Canvas canvas;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

public GameLoopActivityLayout(Context context) {
    //all necessary initializations here...
    button = new Button(context);
    button.setEnabled(true);
    button.setLeft(10);
    button.setTop(20);
}

//render function called during game loop
private void render() {
    if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
        return;
    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    //draw all game objects to canvas...
    button.draw(canvas);
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating custom Views does not prevent you from having XML layouts. For example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.yourpackage.GameLoopLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_loop_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can use margins and `android:layout_gravity` to place the button wherever you like.

In code, get access to your `GameLoopLayout` like you would any other view:

```
// inside of onCreate()
mGameLoopLayout = (GameLoopLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_loop_layout);
// do setup with GameLoopLayout
```

Comment: Ok, somehow I've made it work, even though I'm quite lost tbh. Could you explain to me what's being done here, please? Here's the onCreate method:

setContentView(R.layout.game_loop);

layout = (GameLoopLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_loop_layout);

Comment: @Tirafesi What are you confused about? This is the standard way to do UI on android. You pass an XML layout to`setContentView()`, then you look up the view by the ID that you set in the XML. That's all that's happening.

Comment: I've finally understood it! I thought that my custom view was the same thing as a layout, and that's why i had to setContentView(myCustomLayout). But now i've realized that i am simply creating my own view object, which then i put inside the xml file, like if it was a button, or textView etc. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5):

**try to below code :**

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

// add button
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("Button added dynamically!");
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
b.setId(MY_BUTTON);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
ll.addView(b);
```

Comment: Care to explain how this works? What is the linearLayout2, and where do i get it? same question for id My_BUTTON

Comment: @Tirafesi private static final int MY_BUTTON = 100; add this in your code.